# Undefined function in Go located at local package

Tags: go

I'm new with Go and I'm trying to build an API, but I'm having some problems at importing functions located at another local package.

My folder structure looks like the following:

```
├── app.go //at package "main"
└── middleware
    ├── authentication.go // package "middleware"
```

I'm trying to import the functions inside the authentication.go file like that:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "./middleware" //Also tried "middleware"
)
```

Thinking that's an import problem because if I move the functions to the same package and folder, it works fine.

The func I'm trying to use also starts with caps, so there shouldn't be a problem importing it:

```
func AuthMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
   //...
}
```

What's wrong with my code? Also, what's the best way to import a local package without having to write the whole path?

I'm using Go 1.15.2, and checked all related S.O posts, but none looks to solve my problem.

EDIT :

Whenever you use a function located at another package, you have to refer first to the package. I was trying to call my function as `AuthMiddleware(parameters)` but the right way to call it was `middleware.AuthMiddleware(parameters)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use dot import paths like this, it is not recommended. Use the relative path for your go src dir (which can be local only, it doesn't have to be online) and it'll work fine.

So something like

```
 import "me.com/api/middleware"
```

Then to avoid stutter perhaps:

```
 middleware.Auth()
```

Comment: That was it! Whenever I used middleware.Auth() it started working! Such a stupid mistake, forgot I had to refer to the package first when calling a method. I used the import path "./middleware", but had to refer to the package when calling the method. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, why isn't recommended using dot import paths?

Comment: They're normally referred to as relative import paths in Go, and are hardly ever used, I think they were added early on, but they don't work sometimes with various tools like go install or go test or go get and if you ever share your code they'll break so it's easier just to start as you mean to go on, it's also more explicit about where the code is. So I would strongly recommend just going with the style above rather than using "./pkg". Relative paths are used so infrequently nowadays it's quite hard to find docs about them but if you search for that term you'll find reasons why not to use.

Comment: Changed the code path to work with "project/package" import, thanks a lot for the tips!!.

Answer (score 1):

There is two way to call function from another package

1. You can use package or alias to call function

With package name

```
package main

import (
    "./middleware" 
)

middleware.Auth();
```

With alias

```
package main

import (
mid  "./middleware" 
)

mid.Auth();
```

2. You can import whole package by using . , after that you do not need to use alias or package name to call function. You can use call function directly with function name

   ```
    package main

    import (
     . "./middleware" 
    )

    Auth();
   ```